# 4148ST diode marking?

Tags: diodes

I ordered some (what I thought to be) 1N4148 diodes. However, the part number on the diodes I received reads: 4148ST. I have searched the realms of <strike>Google</strike> DuckDuckGo, and have found no indications whatsoever on what the ST means. Are the diodes I received 1N41148s? Or are they some other kind of diode that I could not find a datasheet for?

Comment: Which manufacturer are the diodes from?

Comment: You worry too much about the markings. I have here 1N4148 diodes with no markings at all, OK only a ring indicating the cathode. In doubt, get your multimeter in diode test mode. Test that it works as a diode (it probably will). Enjoy your diodes. For most circuits where a 1N4148 is needed, almost any other small silicon diode will just work. So stop worrying about the markings, they mean very little.

Comment: Is it a SOT-523 capsule?

Comment: No. Its a DO-35 package.

Comment: They are fine. Each manufacturer labels them differently.

Comment: Google say "1N4148ST" are made at least by STM, Kynix, and Semtech,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many manufacturers that produce the same part or compatible one, use slightly different markings. For example the classic general purpose NPN transistor BC548 is often mark as C548 as well. This practice is very common.

Your 4148ST diode is for sure the same part as or compatible with the 1N4148.

For more detail about what the manufacturer meant by 'ST', you need to get the datasheet from that exact manufacturer and look for a section typically named 'Marking'. Some times, particularly in SMD stuff, markings in components tend to differ from the real model name they are known for, so this datasheet section becomes almost the only clue available for identifying the part and its characteristics.

In case the brand is unknown for being a cheap China fake generic clone... part,the only hope is trying to find the manufacturer they tried to clone and check its datasheet.